# Speak UI - SearchPanel config setting

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-speak-ui

I am currently working in Speak Ui .I need to display all child of Root which belongs from some specific template . For that I am using "SearchPanel Config" to do template and root setting . After doing this setting I noticed its not talking template setting from "SearchPanel Config" and displaying all Items . I am new to speak UI . Please help me .

Answer (score 3):

When you say "not taking the template" are the results not filtered as you expect?

When configuring your Search Panel Config template you should add the required item ids in the **Root** and **Template** fields.

[image: Search Panel Config]

You then need to edit the properties of the SearchDataSource rendering

[image: SearchDataSource]

To set the **SearchConfigItemId** to the SearchPanelConfig item you previously edited using the TreeList to select the required config item.

[image: SearchConfigItemId]

[image: Search Config Tree List]

You can verify the appropriate configuration is being passed by checking the Network Tab in your browser to see the calls being made by your SPEAK component.

You should see - [hostname]-/item/v1/sitecore/shell?search=&searchConfig=%7B**C01B6B84-4D24-4214-B663-52902F43F113**%7D&sc_content=master&language=en where the **searchConfig** parameter is the value of the **SearchConfigItemId** you previously set

Additionally look in your Sitecore log files and verify what the query being passed to the search index is, see below for an example of mine.

> 21376 08:35:37 INFO  Query -
>   (((_path:(7cc230f160a84d979c06c738a1334c6e) AND _language:(en)) AND
>   _templatename:("Your Template Name")) AND -__hidden:(1)) 21376 08:35:37 INFO  Serialized Query - ?q=(((_path:(7cc230f160a84d979c06c738a1334c6e) AND
>   _language:(en)) AND _templatename:("Your Template Name")) AND -__hidden:(1))&rows=500&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)&sort=_name
>   asc

Comment: Thanks Wesley for reply . I cant use browse button as my template is in master Database . And browse button will only take core database itemes .

Comment: Hi Wesley , I did all settings . But still its include root items ( Ex : RootItem have 5 children. So with this setting it should show only 5 in display but its showing 6 ( included root item itself ) .

Comment: What does your query being passed to the search index look like?

Comment: Checked the documentation for SPEAK from 7.2 and the SearchPanel Config is the same - https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/speak_component_reference_sc72_a4.pdf Look at page 174

Comment: Just a thought is your Root item of a different template type to your child items?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90979/discussion-between-soni-and-wesley-lomax).